# How to fix this issue while trying to attach event receiver via powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, event-receivers

I tying to attach event receiver via powershell but facing this issue:

```
$list = (get-spweb http://site/it).lists['IT Support Request']
$def = $list.EventReceivers.Add() 
$def.Assembly = "$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" 
$def = $list.EventReceivers.Add()
$def.Assembly = "$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
$def.Class = "esolution_STG.CreateITSupportTicket.CreateITSupportTicket"
$def.Type = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverType]::ItemUpdated
$def.Name = "CreateITSupportTicketItemUpdated";
$def.Synchronization = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPEventReceiverSynchronization]::Synchronous
$def.Update()
```

Here is the issue:

> Exception calling "Update" with "0" argument(s): "Could n assembly
>   '.Project.AssemblyFullName$' or one of its depen cannot find the file
>   specified." At line:1 char:1
>   + $def.Update()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], Metho
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use fully qualified name of your assembly (e.g. `MyNamespace.MyAssembly, version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089`) instead of `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$`. [Here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdeveloperdocs/2010/11/05/quick-tip-find-the-four-part-name-for-an-assembly/) is a guide on how to get it from within Visual Studio. As far as I know, `$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$` can only be used decoratively (XML).

Keep in mind that your code is adding two event receivers and only the last one is updated:

`$def = $list.EventReceivers.Add() 
$def.Assembly = "$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" 
$def = $list.EventReceivers.Add()
$def.Assembly = "$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"`